# Run celery worker with a compiled python module compiled using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, pyinstaller, worker

I have a simple celery module (`worker.py`) that looks like:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('celery')

@app.task(bind=True)
def some_task(self):
    print('HELLO WORLD')
```

I'm compiling the module using `pyinstaller`:

```
python3 -m PyInstaller --onefile worker.py
```

Then, I can run a celery worker with the python module quite easily using the command:

```
celery -A worker.app worker -l info
```

*My question is:* How can I run the celery worker with the compiled version of the module (Created by PyInstaller)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for this problem is to run the worker from inside a python module, so for example:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('celery', fixups=[])

@app.task(bind=True)
def some_task(self):
    print('HELLO WORLD')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.worker_main(argv=['worker', '--loglevel=info'])
```

and then we can use pyinstaller to compile this module:

```
pyinstaller --one-file module.py --additional-hooks-dir=pyinstaller_hooks_folder
```

the `additional-hooks-dir` flag is for pyinstaller to know how to collect celery's submodules, etc.. we need to have `pyinstaller_hooks_folder` in our project folder and a celery hook file in it:

```
Project_folder
└── pyinstaller_hooks_folder
    └──hook-celery.py
```

*hook-celery.py file:*

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all('celery')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible (but please do correct me if it is).

Firstly, `pyinstaller` generates an executable and thus a file that comes from the output of `pyinstaller` is a hardcoded bin and can run perfectly without an interpreter, dependencies, etc.

From the [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/)

> PyInstaller bundles a Python application and all its dependencies into a single package. The user can run the packaged app without installing a Python interpreter or any modules.

`Celery` requires the use of a python interpreter to run the python code, i.e., `Celery` is a simple library that is imported and integrates with the existing python code to run the file. Thus, an executable file that is compiled with `pyinstaller` shouldn't work in this scenario.